# Vibrating String problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We have the following PDE $$ u_{tt} = c^{2}u_{xx} = 0$$ with $x \in [0,1]$ and $t \in (0,\infty)$.

$$\begin{cases} 
      u(x,0) = 0 \\
      u_{t}(x,0) = x\sin{x\pi} & x\in [0,1] \\
      u(0,t) = u(1,t) 
   \end{cases}
$$

my attempt at the solution:

We set $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$, so the PDE becomes $X(x)T^{''}(t) = c^2 X^{''}(x)T(t) = 0 $ $$ \frac{T^{''}(t)}{T(t)} = c^2 \frac{X^{''}(x)}{X(x)} = 0$$.

The T problem reduces to $T^{''}(t) = 0 \implies T = c_{1}t + c_{2}$.

The X problem reduces to $c^2 X^{''} = 0 \implies X^{''} = \frac{1}{c^2}(b_{1}x + b_{2})$.

If we apply the IC, we see that $u(0,t) = \frac{b_{2}}{c^2}(c_{1}t + c_{2}) = \frac{b_{2} + b_{1}}{c^2}(c_{1}t + c_{2}) \implies b_{1} = 0$. Also $u(x,0) = \frac{b_{2}c_{2}}{c^2} = 0$. This implies that the only solution is the trivial one. I feel like i did something wrong somewhere. I know how the general solution for the PDE is defined but here $\lambda = 0$

Comment: Did you want to write $u_{tt}-c^2\,u_{xx}=0$?

Comment: no, that's how the problem is stated.

Comment: I asked because, as stated, you can easily show that $u=pxt+qx+rt+s$ for some constants $p,q,r,s$.  Then, the boundary conditions cannot be satisfied.

Comment: Furthermore, since you said that this is a problem about vibration, it is natural to think about the wave equation.

Comment: I was thinking that I did something wrong. So, i'm right, that the only solution is the trivial one.

Comment: @Humberto Dial : Obviously there is a typo in the wording of the problem. Do not always put undue reliance on what is typed. Correct the PDE according to the physical model.